# setInterval и console.log

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что не так.

```
let timerId1 = setInterval(() => console.log('tick from timer 1'), 1000);

// остановить через 5 сек
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId1); console.log('timer 1 - stoped'); }, 5000);
```

Почему console.log срабатывает только один раз? Причём если заменить console.log на alert, то будет ок:

```
let timerId1 = setInterval(() => alert('tick from timer 1'), 1000);
```

И ещё больше смущает это:

```
let timerId1 = setInterval(() => console.log('tick from timer 1'), 1000);
let timerId2 = setInterval(() => console.log('tick from timer 2'), 1000);

// остановить через 5 сек
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId1); console.log('timer 1 - stoped'); }, 5000);
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId2); console.log('timer 2 - stoped'); }, 5000);
```

Здесь всё работает, как и должно - 4(5) тика + stop. Почему-то в FF 4 тика, в Chrome - 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя в консоли справа от вывода "tick from timer 1" должен увеличиваться счетчик. Каждое его увеличение - еще один вывод сообщения. Если происходит именно так, то все работает, не волнуйся. :)

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь вижу. Не обратил внимание на эти числа.

От себя добавлю:
`let timerId1 = setInterval(() => console.log('tick from timer 1 - ' + Date.now()), 1000);`
Если так сделать, то начинает выводить все сообщения. Наглядненько.